# how can i return back to same fragment when user cuts outgoing call

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

How can i return back to same fragment when user cuts outgoing call made by onClick() method of button 
 i have a button in fragment from where i open dialog and on dialog's button click phone call activity is starting
here i put some code and my call state listener kindly help me

// phone call made

```
String temp = "tel:+91"+"xxxxxxxxxx";
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(temp));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
```

// my phone call state listener

```
private class PhoneCallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
    private boolean isSystemCalling = false;
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state)
            {
                isSystemCalling = true;
            }
            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state)
            {
                if (isSystemCalling)
                {
                    if(!active)
                    {
                        db.update_activity(Utilities.CONST_SYS_STATUS,Utilities.STATUS_DEACTIVE);
                        update();
                    }
                    else
                    {
db.update_activity(Utilities.CONST_SYS_STATUS,Utilities.STATUS_ACTIVE);
                        update();
                    }
                    isSystemCalling = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below codes and it's working as you want. It's returning after call.

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + contactNumber);
Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                // TODO: Consider calling
                                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
     return;
}
mContext.startActivity(dial);
```

Try using that if it works for you.

Comment: yeah it works and if i'm not wrong i put it before this line ,startActivity(callIntent); right ?

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake, as far as I can understand with codes.
Anyway, you can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.Keep coding :) @ravi_koriya